# Error in creating Kubernetes minikube replicaset yaml file

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, replicaset

Error from server (BadRequest): error when creating "replicaset.yml": ReplicaSet in version "v1" cannot be handled as a ReplicaSet: strict decoding error: unknown field "spec.template.metadata:"

Here is the my yaml file.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: ReplicaSet
metadata:
  name: myapp-replicaset
  labels:
    app: myapp
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myapp
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata::
      name:: nginx-2
      labels:
        app: myapp
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: nginx
          image: nginx
```

I was expecting to create three pods by running the command below:

`kubectl create -f replicatset.yaml`

Comment: It's a little unusual to directly create a ReplicaSet.  Do you mean to create a Deployment instead (which will indirectly create a ReplicaSet)?

Answer (score 0):

`metadata::` and `name:: nginx-2`

It should be have only one `:`

`metadata:`

Comment: Thank you Thang!  I can't beleive my eyeset are that bad:)

Comment: Can you mark my answer is corrected answer ?